# How to apply styles to even or odd rows in table?

Tags: javascript, html

i want to apply style to even/odd rows of a table, i know its super easy with css and jquery. but i am trying to put that table in windows gadget and this below code only works in browser not in that gadget.

```
table.data-Tables tbody tr:nth-child(even){
    background-image: none;
    background:#ECF0F1;
}
```

The Above Code i have tried with CSS do not work, css do works but some codes of css do not work on gadget, may be new css is not acceptable by gadgets..
But anyhow if CSS do not works then i want to try javascript.
Can anyone make it possible in java script to add some styles to even row.

Table:

```
<table class="data-Tables" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Room</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>Admin Room No: 36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Director Room No: 36</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the rows and add a class to just the even ones. If they don't have any other class value, then:

```
function addClassToEvenRows(table) {
  var rows = table.rows;
  for (var i=0, iLen=rows.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    rows[i].className = i%2? '' : 'even';
  }
}
```

will do the trick. If there might be other class values, then:

```
function addClassToEvenRows(table) {
  var rows = table.rows;
  var className;

  for (var i=0, iLen=rows.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if ((i + 1)%2) {
      rows[i].className += (rows[i].className.length? ' ' : '') + even;
    }
  }
}
```